# Parse beforeDelete for Installation

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com as my mobile backend. I wanna send push to the device which is been deleted from `Parse Installation` class. I tried using beforeDelete function, It sends push to all devices of the channel except the device which is been deleted. Here is the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete(Parse.Installation, function(request, response) {
    // code here
    console.log(request.object);

    Parse.Push.send({
        channels: request.object.get('channels'),
      data: {
          action: "com.example.UPDATE_STATUS",
          alert: "Deleted "+request.object.get('uniqueId'),
          name: "Installation",
          method: "delete",
          item: request.object.get('uniqueId')
      }
    }, {
      success: function() {
        // Push was successful
          response.success();
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // Handle error
          response.error(error);
      }
    });
});
```

Here the (uniqueId) is the android device id. How can I send push to the device which is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you deleting installations?  This isn't recommended.

This won't work as by the time the push actually gets processed, the installation will be deleted and won't match the push query.

Comment: Thanks @Fosco for your reply. But is their any other solution?

Comment: Why are you deleting installations?

Comment: I have got a scenario in which _Installation class will have a field named identifier. identifier will hold some unique value which are entered by the user. Imagine identifier already has a value 7 and the user is entering 7 then the installation  should replace the existing installation which has the value 7.

Comment: This data should likely not go in the installation then, and be in a separate class that links to / is linked from the installation.